# How do I select a postgres Many-to-One relationship as a single row?

Tags: postgresql, many-to-one

I have a many-to-one relationship between Animals and their attributes. Because different Animals have different attributes, I want to be able to select all animals with their attribute name as a column header and NULL values where that animal does not have that attribute.

Like so...

```
TABLE_ANIMALS
ID  | ANIMAL      | DATE          | MORE COLS....
1   | CAT         | 2012-01-10    | ....
2   | DOG         | 2012-01-10    | ....
3   | FROG        | 2012-01-10    | ....
...

TABLE_ATTRIBUTES
ID  | ANIMAL_ID | ATTRIBUE_NAME     | ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
1   | 1         | noise             | meow
2   | 1         | legs              | 4
3   | 1         | has_fur           | TRUE
4   | 2         | noise             | woof
5   | 2         | legs              | 4
6   | 3         | noise             | croak
7   | 3         | legs              | 2
8   | 3         | has_fur           | FALSE
...

QUERY RESULT
ID  | ANIMAL    | NOISE   | LEGS  | HAS_FUR 
1   | CAT       | meow    | 4     | TRUE
2   | DOG       | woof    | 4     | NULL
3   | FROG      | croak   | 2     | FALSE
```

How would I do this? To reiterate, it's important that all the columns are there even if one Animal doesn't have that attribute, such as "DOG" and "HAS_FUR" in this example. If it doesn't have the attribute, it should just be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a simple join, aggregation and group by?

```sql
create table table_animals(id int, animal varchar(10), date date);
create table table_attributes(id varchar(10), animal_id int, attribute_name varchar(10), attribute_value varchar(10));

insert into table_animals values (1, 'CAT',  '2012-01-10'),
                                 (2, 'DOG',  '2012-01-10'),
                                 (3, 'FROG',  '2012-01-10');

insert into table_attributes values (1, 1, 'noise', 'meow'),
                                    (2, 1, 'legs', 4),
                                    (3, 1, 'has_fur', TRUE),
                                    (4, 2, 'noise', 'woof'),
                                    (5, 2, 'legs', 4),
                                    (6, 3, 'noise', 'croak'),
                                    (7, 3, 'legs', 2),
                                    (8, 3, 'has_fur', FALSE);

select ta.animal,
       max(attribute_value) filter (where attribute_name = 'noise') as noise,
       max(attribute_value) filter (where attribute_name = 'legs') as legs,
       max(attribute_value) filter (where attribute_name = 'has_fur') as has_fur
from table_animals ta
left join table_attributes tat on tat.animal_id = ta.id
group by ta.animal
```

Here's a [rextester sample](https://rextester.com/HNQZ49115)

Additionally you can change the aggregation to `MAX CASE WHEN...` but `MAX FILTER WHERE` has better performance.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks!